# After I add mpl-token-metadata I'm not able to build the program

Tags: solana-program, rust

|
28 | #[derive(BorshSerialize, BorshDeserialize, PartialEq, Eq, Debug, Clone)]
|                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `borsh::BorshDeserialize` is not implemented for `mpl_token_auth_rules::payload::Payload`
|
= help: the following other types implement trait `borsh::BorshDeserialize`:
()
(T0, T1)
(T0, T1, T2)
(T0, T1, T2, T3)
(T0, T1, T2, T3, T4)
(T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5)
(T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6)
(T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7)
and 161 others
note: required for `AuthorizationData` to implement `borsh::BorshDeserialize`
--> src/processor/mod.rs:58:26
|
58 | #[derive(BorshSerialize, BorshDeserialize, PartialEq, Eq, Debug, Clone)]
|                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ unsatisfied trait bound introduced in this `derive` macro
59 | pub struct AuthorizationData {
|            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
= note: 1 redundant requirement hidden
= note: required for `Option<AuthorizationData>` to implement `borsh::BorshDeserialize`
= help: see issue #48214
= help: add `#![feature(trivial_bounds)]` to the crate attributes to enable
= note: this error originates in the derive macro `BorshDeserialize` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error[E0277]: the trait bound `mpl_token_auth_rules::payload::Payload: borsh::BorshSerialize` is not satisfied
--> src/processor/mod.rs:58:10
|
58 | #[derive(BorshSerialize, BorshDeserialize, PartialEq, Eq, Debug, Clone)]
|          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `borsh::BorshSerialize` is not implemented for `mpl_token_auth_rules::payload::Payload`
|

Answer (score 1):

Try running:

```
cargo update -p borsh@0.10.3 --precise 0.9.3
```

Comment: I'm getting below error

error: failed to select a version for the requirement `borsh = "^0.10.3"`
candidate versions found which didn't match: 0.9.3
location searched: crates.io index
required by package `solana-program v1.16.7`
    ... which satisfies dependency `solana-program = ">=1.14, <1.17"` (locked to 1.16.7) of package `anchor-lang v0.28.0`
    ... which satisfies dependency `anchor-lang = "^0.28.0"` (locked to 0.28.0) of package `eco-market v0.1.0 (/home/sn/Documents/projects/eco-market/programs/eco-market)`
perhaps a crate was updated and forgotten to be re-vendored?

Answer (score 1):

You're seeing this error because of a breaking change in the Solana SDK in version 1.16. The older versions of `mpl-token-metadata` don't support 1.16 yet, so mixing them will cause build errors.

In the meantime, if you want to use borsh 0.10 and Solana 1.16, you can upgrade to mpl-token-metadata version 2.0, which is on beta and supports 1.16: https://crates.io/crates/mpl-token-metadata/2.0.0-beta.1